# Change font in application

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey

Are there any simple ways to change font in the whole program? I have desktop fmx (delphi xe7) application, which use styles but for some users it's nessasary to configure this thing.

I understantand that it may looks like this:

```
LabelReceptSign.StyledSettings := [];
LabelReceptSign.FontColor:= ComboColorBox1.Color;
LabelReceptSign.Font.Size:= SpinBoxReceptFontsize.Value;
LabelReceptSign.Font.Family:= ComboBoxFontRec.Selected.Text;
```

for each component, but it will be a very huge code! Using FindComponent procedure with name itteration generation 'label' + inttost(i) I could make it shorter, but whatever it's very poor way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why won't styles work for your situation?

Comment: Well, 7% of users voted to have that opportunity in the program.

Comment: You might consider looking into style hooks. This allows you to customize how controls are painted. See https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/changing-the-color-of-edit-controls-with-vcl-styles-enabled/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wrote code, it's working, except comboedit and radiobutton - I don't know why, but change them in another procedure. Also I don't know what to do with mainmenu. The procedure changes only popup menu items.

```
Procedure FontchangeApply;
   var
i : integer;
begin

if Programfont.usefont = true  then begin

 with form2 do begin
   for i := 0 to form2.ComponentCount-1 do begin
    try
       if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'label') then begin
             (Components[i] as TLabel).StyledSettings:= [];
                   (Components[i] as TLabel).font.Size:=    programfont.programfont.Size;
                (Components[i] as TLabel).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
                (Components[i] as TLabel).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
          end;

          if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'stringgrid') then begin
              (Components[i] as Tstringgrid).StyledSettings:= [];
              (Components[i] as Tstringgrid).TextSettings.font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
              (Components[i] as Tstringgrid).TextSettings.font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
              (Components[i] as Tstringgrid).TextSettings.fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
           end;

          if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'button') then begin
           (Components[i] as Tbutton).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as Tbutton).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as Tbutton).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as Tbutton).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
          end;

         if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Menuitem') then begin
           (Components[i] as TMenuitem).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TMenuitem).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TMenuitem).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TMenuitem).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
         end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Tabitem') then begin
           (Components[i] as TTabitem).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TTabitem).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TTabitem).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TTabitem).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'DateEdit') then begin
           (Components[i] as TDateEdit).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TDateEdit).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TDateEdit).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TDateEdit).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'TimeEdit') then begin
           (Components[i] as TTimeEdit).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TTimeEdit).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TTimeEdit).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TTimeEdit).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Spinbox') then begin
           (Components[i] as TSpinbox).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TSpinbox).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TSpinbox).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TSpinbox).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Memo') then begin
           (Components[i] as TMemo).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TMemo).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TMemo).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TMemo).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Checkbox') then begin
           (Components[i] as TCheckbox).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TCheckbox).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TCheckbox).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TCheckbox).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'Edit') then begin
           (Components[i] as TEdit).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TEdit).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TEdit).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TEdit).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

       if  ContainsText(Components[i].ClassName, 'ComboEdit') then begin
             //showmessage('nashel comboedit');
           (Components[i] as TCustomComboEdit).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TCustomComboEdit).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TEdit).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TEdit).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'GroupBox') then begin
           //showmessage('nashel groupbox');
           (Components[i] as TGroupBox).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TGroupBox).font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TGroupBox).font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TGroupBox).fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

        if  ContainsText(Components[i].Name, 'RadioButton') then begin
            showmessage('nashel radiobutton');
           (Components[i] as TRadiobutton).StyledSettings:= [];
           (Components[i] as TRadiobutton).textsettings.font.Size:= programfont.programfont.Size;
           (Components[i] as TRadiobutton).textsettings.font.family:= programfont.programfont.family;
           (Components[i] as TRadiobutton).textsettings.fontcolor:= programfont.programfontcolor;
        end;

      except
        showmessage('Error in'+ Components[i].Name);
       end;
     end;

   end;
   end;
  end;
```